# Changing chart theme dynamically in zingchart is not working

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I am trying to change the chart theme dynamically using this code:

```
changeTheme(e) {
        this.previewService.chartConfig.theme = this.themes[e.target.attributes.value.value];
      }
```

This is the way I am changing the theme dynamically, it got reflected in json source of chart but it is not updating the actual theme. 
Could you show me a working example for same?
Please check this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/pshiral/30955m70/7/

Answer (score 5):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

Themes work at the highest level in our library. We build pieces of the chart based on attributes in the theme working our way in a top to bottom fashion. Because of this, you can only set and update a theme at the render level. This means you will have to destroy your chart and re-render it to changes themes. Check out the following:

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "bar", 
 series : [
  {
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});

function changeTheme(e) {
  zingchart.exec('myChart','destroy');
  zingchart.render({ 
   id : 'myChart', 
   data : myConfig, 
   height : 400, 
   width : 600,
   theme: this.id
  });
}
document.getElementById('light').addEventListener('click',changeTheme);
document.getElementById('dark').addEventListener('click',changeTheme);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
  <button id='light'>Light Theme</button>
  <button id='dark'>Dark Theme</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more thing is, to change the background, there is no effort needed to re-render the chart so I think it should work same way with theme too. Could you please provide more optimized way? Is 'id' required everywhere? Can we eliminate using id everywhere?

Comment: I have attached the jsfiddle. Please have a look. I want to use customized theme dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

I have updated our Angular Directive to watch for changes on the zcRender object. It will take care of chart cleanup and re-rendering the chart for you. The latest version 1.2.1 can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zingchart-angularjs). I put together a small demo in a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kBnyf1pByLcgRrMScSNC?p=preview) demonstrating the changes.

```
                // If defaults or theme has changed. 
            // Destroy and re-render chart
            $scope.$watch('zcRender', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
              if(initializing.render){
                  initializing.render = !initializing.render;
                  return;
              }
              // console.log('---newValue',newValue)
              // console.log('---oldValue',oldValue)
              // console.log('---scope',scope)

              zingchart.exec(scope.id, 'destroy');
              scope.zcRender = newValue;
              scope.renderChart();
            },true);

            // Break render function out of link so we can consistently
            // call the same rendering algorithm
            $scope.renderChart = function (){
              var id = $element.attr('id');
              //Defaults
              var _json = {
                  data : {
                      type : 'line',
                      series : []
                  },
                  width : 600,
                  height: 400
              };

              //Add render object.
              if($scope.zcRender){
                  mergeObject($scope.zcRender, _json);
              }

              //Add JSON object
              if($scope.zcJson){
                  mergeObject($scope.zcJson, _json.data);
              }

              //Add Values
              if($scope.zcValues){
                injectValues($scope.zcValues, _json.data);
              }

              //Add other properties
              _json.data.type = ($attrs.zcType) ? $attrs.zcType : _json.data.type;
              _json.height = ($attrs.zcHeight) ? $attrs.zcHeight : _json.height;
              _json.width = ($attrs.zcWidth) ? $attrs.zcWidth : _json.width;
              _json.id = id;

              //Set the box-model of the container element if the height or width are defined as 100%.
              if(_json.width === "100%" && !$element.css('width')){
                  $element.css('width', '100%');
              }
              if(_json.height === "100%" && !$element.css('height')){
                  $element.css('height', '100%');
              }
              zingchart.render(_json);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use defaults instead of theme :  please check attached fiddle ,
let me know is it the same thing you are looking?

`zingchart.render({ 
            id : 'myChart', 
            data : $scope.data, 
            height : 300, 
            width : 500,
            defaults: $scope.myTheme
        });`

https://jsfiddle.net/omix3379/4k0v06cL/

Thanks.